# Post data with jQuery using a variable

Tags: jquery, post

I want to post data with jQuery. When I post detailed JSON, it works. But when I post JSON using a variable, it's not working.

**working**

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {

    let urlSave = 'http://localhost/playlist/api/playlist.php?type=playlist';
    $.post(urlSave, { "name": "test", "image": "IMG/play.png", "songs": [{ "name": "Just people", "url": "src/af/AF-05-Just people.mp3" }, { "name": "Send me power", "url": "src/af/AF-09-Send me power.mp3" }] }, function (data, status) {
        alert(data.success);
    });
});
```

**not working**

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {

    let urlSave = 'http://localhost/playlist/api/playlist.php?type=playlist';
    var d='{ "name": "test", "image": "IMG/play.png", "songs": [{ "name": "Just people", "url": "src/af/AF-05-Just people.mp3" }, { "name": "Send me power", "url": "src/af/AF-09-Send me power.mp3" }] }';
    $.post(urlSave, d, function (data, status) {
        alert(data.success);
   });
});
```

I have no idea where I'm wrong. 
I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Remove the single quotes at the start and end of `d` (you're sending a string instead of an object)

Comment: The above comment is the answer. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much thanks to you the problem has been solved. I've spent a lot of time on this stupid thing.